# My PC doesn't recognize my GTablet through USB

Tags: usb-connection-mode, usb-drivers, viewsonic-gtablet

I have a GTablet GingerEdition. It has no OS, hence I need to install it from my PC, but when I connect the tablet to my PC I can´t see it as a USB device. The PC says that there are no drivers.

Comment: Missing USB drivers for the operating system on the PC. Just go to the manufacturer website, download the correct USB drivers, install it, then connect your GTablet. The operating system, like Windows, will automatically search for suitable USB drivers to enable the connection between your tablet and PC.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if it works. But first of all update the driver from sdk\extras\google\usb_driver for your device. Also, check in root mode if any help is available.